# align variables name in android studio

Tags: android, variables, android-studio, indentation

I'm trying to find a way to align all the variable names and classes names in android studio, is there a way to do this automatically?

For example I want android studio to do this automatically:

```
    private void    someFunction()
{
    int             someVariable;
    TextView        anotherVariable;

}
```

For now I'm doing it manually by it would be easier if it could do it automatically.
thanks

Comment: Try to find something here
"File" [menu]/"Settings"/"Code Style"/"Alignment and Braces"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Android Studio 1.3 you can enable this here:

`Project Settings | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Group declarations | Align fields in columns`

[image]

To reformat your code manually, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or using the menu `Code | Reformat code...`).

More information about reformating source code can be found on the [IntelliJ Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: You need to go to `Code` - `Reformat Code...` after this operation to let it have effect.

Comment: I assumed, the TO would know how to trigger reformatting. But I've updated my answer, so it's complete.

Comment: I wanted to do the opposite, but you answer is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Code > Auto-indent Lines (Ctrl-Alt-I)

Comment: well it isn't the auto indent of lines I'm talking about but rather hte indetation of the names of variables that I want.

Comment: Oh ok, but just FYI this is not standard Java indentation (same goes for brace on new line) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Yes I know, this is the way of doing for C norm at my school, so I guess I'll just have to abandon that habit (which is BTW more readable than the other one... :( )
Thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome. I agree that brace at a line by itself is more readable and more consistent (the closing brace is always at a line by itself...).